# List files in directory separately python

Tags: python

I'm working on a program that has a list of all files in a folder. Right now it only outputs the files as one entity, like one string. I need the files to each be displayed separately. Is there a way to do this?
This is the code I use:

```
import os
options = [
    "Select a publisher",
    os.listdir("C:/Users/bodig/Desktop/ad.olo exporter/config")
]
print(options)
```

The output:

```
['Select a publisher', ['bdu.json', 'ea.json', 'frz.json', 'fs.json', 'nfz.json', 'rht.json', 'taa.json', 'vol.json']]
```

The problem is that they are all one Entity. I can't figure out how to display them in a line. The output that I want is like this:

```
'Select a publisher'
'bdu.json'
'ea.json'
'frz.json'
'fs.json'
'nfz.json'
'rht.json'
'taa.json'
'vol.json'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options = ["Select a publisher"] + os.listdir("C:/Users/bodig/Desktop/ad.olo exporter/config")

for option in options:
    print(option)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your problem, but with putting the file names out in separate lines I can help (as I think that is what you want). Just use a for loop:

```
print("Select a publisher:")
for i in os.listdir("C:/Users/bodig/Desktop/ad.olo exporter/config"):
        print(i)
```

To print them all in one line, separated by commas, you could use:

```
print("Select a publisher:")
my_text = ""
for i in os.listdir("C:/Users/bodig/Desktop/ad.olo exporter/config"):
        my_text += i + ", "
print(my_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your print statement, print like below.

```
import os
options = [
    "Select a publisher",
    os.listdir("C:/Users/bodig/Desktop/ad.olo exporter/config")
]

print(options[0], "\n", "\n".join(options[1]))   # modified print
```

Output:

```
Select a publisher 
bdu.json
ea.json
frz.json
fs.json
nfz.json
rht.json
taa.json
vol.json
```